# API for retrieving web site inlinks

Tags: seo, web, search-engine

I am working on a research project in which I need to find the in-links for approx. 170K URIs. My first thoughts were to use the Google or Yahoo APIs but then I realized that Yahoo Boss is now at Bing, which doesn't seem to support inlink queries, and that Google, deprecated its search API a while ago and replaced it with Custom Search, which doesn't seem to support inlink queries over their whole web index.

Are there any alternative solutions I missed? I am looking for a simple Web API that accepts a given URI and returns the inlinks for that URI.

Thx,
B

**Update**:

- Google: for retrieving XML feeds of search results I need to convert a given custom search engine to Google Site Search, which is a commercial service. Even then I am only allowed to retrieved inlinks for a pre-defined set of sites, not for the whole web
- Yahoo: Site Explorer unfortunately shut down and moved to Bing
- Bing: in Bing's Webmaster tools app you can view the inlinks for a specific site, but you cannot query inlinks for arbitrary URIs, because it Bing Webmaster Tools doesn't provide an API yet

Answer (score 0):

[The SEOmoz API](http://www.seomoz.org/api#__utma=100323008.586398451.1326335061.1326335061.1326335061.1&__utmb=100323008.1.10.1326335061&__utmc=100323008&__utmx=-&__utmz=100323008.1326335061.1.1.utmcsr=google%7Cutmccn=%28organic%29%7Cutmcmd=organic%7Cutmctr=open%20site%20explorer&__utmv=-&__utmk=222973083) - If you just need to get total amount of links pointing to a URL you should be able to use the free version.